# Animated underline not showing once link is selected

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm using Bootstrap and SCSS to customize my CSS file. I have a `nav-link` like this:

```
.sidebar .nav-pills .nav-link:hover,
.sidebar .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    @extend %underline-link;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, $sidebar-navitem-background-color 65%, $sidebar-navitem-background-color 65%);
}

.sidebar .nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.sidebar .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    @extend %underline-link;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, darken($sidebar-navitem-background-color, 2) 65%, darken($sidebar-navitem-background-color, 2) 65%);
}

%underline-link {
    color: $underline-link-color;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0;
        background: $underline-link-color;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: center left;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }

    &:hover {
        transition: all 0.4s ease;

        &:before {
            visibility: visible;
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The line is animated as expected when hovering over the item. However, when the item is active, the line disappears.

How do I keep the line showing as long as the item is active?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to make your active state the same as your hover state you need to add the `:active` pseudo class alongside your `:hover` pseudo class in your SCSS. That will ensure that when the user clicks the link (i.e. the link is active) the style remains the same. [More information about active state on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

I have created [a codepen with different styles for hover and active](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/KKeYwRQ?editors=1100) to show the interaction happening. If `:hover` and `:active` have the same styles you would therefore see no difference between the two states.

```
&:hover,
&:active {
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    
    &:before {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge and how our solution tackles it. Answers should also be self-contained; we encourage links, but they should be supplementary, not essential.

Comment: Noted... I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: Then you've got a problem elsewhere. I've added a codepen to the answer above that shows different styles for the two states so you can see that is how you get a style onto :active. Obviously if the styles for :active and :hover are the same you would not notice a change between the two. Also, you're welcome.